# SVG a Paper.js con items interactuables

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

Estoy empezando con esto del canvas y aprendiendo para hacer algo así como esos dibujos coloreables de niños. El caso sería poder hacer el dibujo en ilustrator en SVG, con sus elementos propios, y poder leerlo y que cogiera los elementos individualmente, y no sé si se puede. Estoy probando con las librerias Fabric.js y Paper.js, por separado. Hasta ahora solo he conseguido con el Paper.js coger los elementos individualmente del SVG y ponerlos en el canvas, porque con esa librería me parece más facil poner los Paths, igual algo más complicado los polígonos. A mayores tener que repetir para colorear tampoco me acaba de convencer, pero como digo, estoy aprendiendo y no sé como mejorarlo.

El canvas me queda algo así

```js
function dibujar(nav2){
console.log(nav2);

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

paper.setup('canvas1');

if (nav2 == 'canvas1') {

  var pathfondo = new paper.Path.Rectangle({
      from: [0, 0],
      to: [500, 500],
      strokeColor: 'black',
      fillColor: 'white'
  });

// var pathData1 = '167.22,38.17 233.98,110.49 236.76,220.35 160.27,145.25';
// var pathData2 = 'M466.29,177.47l-59.23-26.66l-56.26,32.12l7.89-62.77l-48.94-41.87l64.1-12.13l26.01-58l31.73,55.27l65.02,6.03l-44.49,46.29L466.29,177.47z';
// var pathData3 = 'm127.61 23.908-7.372-3.4276-7.0028 4.1297 0.98173-8.0703-6.0916-5.3839 7.9787-1.5602 3.238-7.4572 3.9494 7.1061 8.0928 0.77513-5.5379 5.952z';
// var pathData4 = 'm21.53 130.17-7.372-3.4276-7.0028 4.1297 0.98173-8.0703-6.0916-5.3839 7.9787-1.5602 3.238-7.4572 3.9494 7.1061 8.0928 0.77514-5.5379 5.952z';


var path = new paper.Path();
path.add(new paper.Point(0,149.46));
path.add(new paper.Point(0,0));
path.add(new paper.Point(144,0));
path.fullySelected = 'true';
path.closed = 'true';
path.fillColor = 'white';
path.strokeColor = 'black';

var path1 = new paper.Path();
path1.add(new paper.Point(500,149.46));
path1.add(new paper.Point(500,0));
path1.add(new paper.Point(356.05,0.22));
path1.fullySelected = 'true';
path1.closed = 'true';
path1.fillColor = 'white';
path1.strokeColor = 'black';

var path2 = new paper.Path();
path2.add(new paper.Point(0,350.54));
path2.add(new paper.Point(0,500));
path2.add(new paper.Point(144,500));
path2.fullySelected = 'true';
path2.closed = 'true';
path2.fillColor = 'white';
path2.strokeColor = 'black';

var path3 = new paper.Path();
path3.add(new paper.Point(500,350.54));
path3.add(new paper.Point(500,500));
path3.add(new paper.Point(356.05,499.78));
path3.fullySelected = 'true';
path3.closed = 'true';
path3.fillColor = 'white';
path3.strokeColor = 'black';

var path4 = new paper.Path();
path4.add(new paper.Point(167.22,38.17));
path4.add(new paper.Point(233.98,110.49));
path4.add(new paper.Point(236.76,220.35));
path4.add(new paper.Point(160.27,145.25));
path4.fullySelected = 'true';
path4.closed = 'true';
path4.fillColor = 'white';
path4.strokeColor = 'black';

var path5 = new paper.Path();
path5.add(new paper.Point(167.22,458.16));
path5.add(new paper.Point(233.98,385.84));
path5.add(new paper.Point(236.76,275.98));
path5.add(new paper.Point(160.27,351.08));
path5.fullySelected = 'true';
path5.closed = 'true';
path5.fillColor = 'white';
path5.strokeColor = 'black';

var path6 = new paper.Path();
path6.add(new paper.Point(327.21,41.84));
path6.add(new paper.Point(260.46,114.16));
path6.add(new paper.Point(257.68,224.02));
path6.add(new paper.Point(334.17,148.92));
path6.fullySelected = 'true';
path6.closed = 'true';
path6.fillColor = 'white';
path6.strokeColor = 'black';

var path7 = new paper.Path();
path7.add(new paper.Point(327.21,461.83));
path7.add(new paper.Point(260.46,389.51));
path7.add(new paper.Point(257.68,279.65));
path7.add(new paper.Point(334.17,354.75));
path7.fullySelected = 'true';
path7.closed = 'true';
path7.fillColor = 'white';
path7.strokeColor = 'black';

var path8 = new paper.Path();
path8.add(new paper.Point(38.17,325.82));
path8.add(new paper.Point(110.49,259.07));
path8.add(new paper.Point(220.35,256.29));
path8.add(new paper.Point(145.25,332.78));
path8.fullySelected = 'true';
path8.closed = 'true';
path8.fillColor = 'white';
path8.strokeColor = 'black';

var path9 = new paper.Path();
path9.add(new paper.Point(458.16,325.82));
path9.add(new paper.Point(385.84,259.07));
path9.add(new paper.Point(275.98,256.29));
path9.add(new paper.Point(351.08,332.78));
path9.fullySelected = 'true';
path9.closed = 'true';
path9.fillColor = 'white';
path9.strokeColor = 'black';

var path10 = new paper.Path();
path10.add(new paper.Point(41.84,165.83));
path10.add(new paper.Point(114.16,232.59));
path10.add(new paper.Point(224.02,235.37));
path10.add(new paper.Point(148.92,158.88));
path10.fullySelected = 'true';
path10.closed = 'true';
path10.fillColor = 'white';
path10.strokeColor = 'black';

var path11 = new paper.Path();
path11.add(new paper.Point(461.83,165.83));
path11.add(new paper.Point(389.51,232.59));
path11.add(new paper.Point(279.65,235.37));
path11.add(new paper.Point(354.75,158.88));
path11.fullySelected = 'true';
path11.closed = 'true';
path11.fillColor = 'white';
path11.strokeColor = 'black';

paper.view.draw();

  pathfondo.onClick = function(event) {
      this.fillColor = color;
      };
  path.onClick = function(event) {
        this.fillColor = color;
        };
  path1.onClick = function(event) {
          this.fillColor = color;
          };
  path2.onClick = function(event) {
        this.fillColor = color;
        };
  path3.onClick = function(event) {
        this.fillColor = color;
        };
  path4.onClick = function(event) {
        this.fillColor = color;
        };
  path5.onClick = function(event) {
        this.fillColor = color;
        };
  path6.onClick = function(event) {
        this.fillColor = color;
        };
  path7.onClick = function(event) {
        this.fillColor = color;
        };
  path8.onClick = function(event) {
        this.fillColor = color;
        };
  path9.onClick = function(event) {
        this.fillColor = color;
        };
  path10.onClick = function(event) {
        this.fillColor = color;
        };
  path11.onClick = function(event) {
        this.fillColor = color;
        };
      }
      };//FIN FUNCION dibujar
```

y el SVG sería este (el mismo del canvas)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" style="enable-background:new 0 0 500 500;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.25;}
</style>
<polygon class="st0" points="0,149.46 0,0 144,0 "/>
<polygon class="st0" points="500,149.46 500,0 356.05,0.22 "/>
<polygon class="st0" points="0,350.54 0,500 144,500 "/>
<polygon class="st0" points="500,350.54 500,500 356.05,499.78 "/>
<polygon class="st0" points="167.22,38.17 233.98,110.49 236.76,220.35 160.27,145.25 "/>
<polygon class="st0" points="167.22,458.16 233.98,385.84 236.76,275.98 160.27,351.08 "/>
<polygon class="st0" points="327.21,41.84 260.46,114.16 257.68,224.02 334.17,148.92 "/>
<polygon class="st0" points="327.21,461.83 260.46,389.51 257.68,279.65 334.17,354.75 "/>
<polygon class="st0" points="38.17,325.82 110.49,259.07 220.35,256.29 145.25,332.78 "/>
<polygon class="st0" points="458.16,325.82 385.84,259.07 275.98,256.29 351.08,332.78 "/>
<polygon class="st0" points="41.84,165.83 114.16,232.59 224.02,235.37 148.92,158.88 "/>
<polygon class="st0" points="461.83,165.83 389.51,232.59 279.65,235.37 354.75,158.88 "/>
</svg>
```

Claro que hacer cada SVG por separado es bastante lioso, y no sé si Paper.js lo puede hacer o no. Sé que insertarlo sin problema, pero por items, ni idea. Como decía, estoy muy verde en esto y no sé por donde tirar. Igual hay otro tipo de librerías que me fueran mejor para este tipo de idea.